# What is the Ruby equivalent of "pythonic"?

Tags: ruby, idioms, vocabulary

In the Python community, the term *pythonic* refers to idiomatic Python<sup>[1]</sup>. Is there an equivalent term in the Ruby community for idiomatic Ruby<sup>[2]</sup>?

<sub>[1] For example, using `enumerate(l)` instead of `range(len(l))` is pythonic.</sub>

<sup>[2] For example, using `.each` instead of `for` is idiomatic Ruby.</sup>

Comment: I noticed that two people voted to close the question. Would this belong better in a different Stack Exchange site? (If you're voting to close, please comment, otherwise I won't learn.)

Comment: I guess I'd use the term 'Ruby-ish'. If you want to explore generally accepted ruby style, there is a community maintained style guide here: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: "The Ruby Way" is the closest I've heard. I generally go with that or "idiomatic Ruby code".

Comment: Ruby-esque? Ruby-ish? (Google appears to prefer the latter).

Comment: @Snowball - Personally, I was incline to vote for migrating it to programmers.stackexchange - but I don't participate in that community so I may be wrong.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen: I see. I'm aware of programmers.SE, but I figured the question would fit better here based on [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions): "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession".

Comment: @Snowball - True - but [something similar is in the StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". There's no problem to face here. So in the end it doesn't fit on either site :P Maybe [Not Programming Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related)?

Comment: I searched for this exact question on google, sorry to see it's closed... the term `pythonic` is quite used on SO and useful to identify precise questions or answers in a web search, so an equivalent ruby term would be useful to know. i'd vote to reopen the question.

Comment: I vote we all start using Rubonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not heard of any such shorthand, presumably because there's no convenient suffix you can append to Ruby to turn it into an adjective :)

If you say something's *idiomatic*, and you're around rubyists, I think everybody will know what you mean.